# DR Process to restore DPM 2010 Backup of 2008 R2 Domain Controller to different hardware

Tags: windows-server-2008, disaster-recovery, scdpm

So I have a DC running Server 2008 R2 on a HP server.

1. I take a full back up using DPM 2010.
2. Then restore the BMR image to the network
3. copy that to a USB drive
4. boot a laptop using the Serer 2008 R2 install media and with the USB drive plugged in.
5. choose to repair and restore the image

The image restores fine and when the machine reboots I get a 0x0000007B BSOD. I'm guessing that this is because I've shifted the image from server to laptop.

I'm trying out a scenario where the office is unavailable and I have our offsite backups. I want to quickly set up a small recovery using several laptops so a couple of staff can deal with customers while we recover the servers properly.

Am I barking up the wrong tree with this BMR recovery? But even if I install Server 2008 and then restore system state of the DC surely I'll hit the same driver errors? Argh help!

Comment: I suppose I'm asking what process is recommended to start from scratch. I.e. office has burnt to the ground and new servers not yet delivered but I have all DPM backups available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPM2010 doesn't support BMR to different hardware.

A 0x0000007B BSOD indicates a problem with the critical boot drivers - most likely for storage but it could be anything.

There are plenty of products out there that support BMR to different hardware but DPM2010 isn't one of them. To restore active directory to different hardware you will need to recreate the DC, install the DPM2010 agent, boot it into directory services restore mode, then perform the recovery. There may be other steps too - all should be well documented.

Comment: Where would you suggest I look for the documentation? My google-fu has failed me. Examples all seem to presume another DC is available.

Comment: I guess from the above I build a server, bring it up to the appropriate patch level, run dcpromo, boot into dsrm and then restore the system state from DPM...

Comment: Paul - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399192.aspx

Comment: I've read though sections of the manual but http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399114.aspx for example doesn't list recovering a DC.

Comment: Ah, the change in thought process led me to http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=326c8a7a-dcad-4333-9050-a6303ff3155c&displaylang=en which might be what I'm after. Some fun weekend reading here!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to rebuild the server from scratch and then restore the system state using the standard 2008 ADDS methods.  Since you dont have the the servers in yet do anything you can to get the DC up so you can then create a new DC on the servers and replicate off the DC on your laptop.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.05.adbackup.aspx